# Iterate over input files, but process them in groups, in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have multiple files with names for instance

```
ahard.txt
asoft.txt
bhard.txt
bsoft.txt
chard.txt
csoft.txt
```

I want to loop over these files, but process them in groups, so that `Xhard.txt` and  `aXsoft.txt` are used as input files, and `X.txt` as output file, where the letter *`X`* stands for `a`, `b`, `c` etc. (it is *actually* a single letter in the filenames).

I have tried:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

i=$(ls *.txt)

for x in $i
do
    pipeline nser=2 input1="${x/soft.txt}" input2="${x/hard.txt}" outfile="${x/hard.txt}"
done
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use parameter expansion to extract the first character of a filename:

```
#! /bin/bash
for soft in ?soft.txt ; do
    letter=${soft:0:1}
    hard=${letter}hard.txt
    if [[ ! -f $hard ]] ; then
        echo "$hard not found" >&2
        continue
    fi
    echo "$soft $hard $letter.txt"
done
```

- `${soft:0:1}` returns the first character from `$soft` (position 0, length 1).

Note that it doesn't report an Xhard with a missing Xsoft.

BTW, using `$(ls ...)` is [almost always wrong](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead). Iterate over an expanded glob as in the snippet above, or populate an array directly without `ls`:

```
files=(*.txt)
```

Comment: Can you explain your code please !!

Comment: I added the explanation of the expansion. Anything else you find confusing?

Comment: What does `?`  do?

Comment: @unicorn: It's a wildcard like `*` but it only matches a single character.

Comment: Thanks it worked !